# replace character in text generated by html.displayfor(function

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, displayfor

A webpage currently gives a device ID with hyphens in the number, I want to replace `-` with `:` instead (that is to say, replace any hyphens with a colon), but only at display time.  I'm pretty confident this is line that is generating the device ID shown on the page:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Function(m) m.DeviceID)</span> <br />
```

Is it possible to change this output to include colons instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a display template.  Create the following partial view  `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/_DeviceWithColons.cshtml`:

```
@model string

@( Model.Replace('-', ':') )
```

Now in your View, specify:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DeviceID, "_DeviceWithColons")
```

You can then later reuse this display template where required.

Comment: thanks to this post I managed to get rid of underscore in the Enum `@model SkillLevelEnums
@( Model.ToString().Replace('_', ' ') )`