# Format text in Html.DisplayFor not working in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Why is the following code not working:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SupplierName.ToString().Replace("\"", ""))
```

I get following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
```

Inner exception:

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, 
single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

Is working with `Templates`, like here in the following question on SO: [replace character in text generated by html.displayfor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377477/replace-character-in-text-generated-by-html-displayforfunction), the only solution?

Looks strange to me to write templates only for formatting some text?

Comment: ok if you use `@Html.Raw(item.SupplierName.ToString().Replace("\"", ""))`, it's working!

Answer (score 2):

Html.DisplayFor is looking for a DisplayTemplate for the data type. I am providing a rough example of using the DisplayFor in your scenario, although likely not needed.

Create a DisplayTemplates folder under Views\Shared and add file called something link RemoveSlashes.cshtml.

```
@model string
@Html.Raw(Model.Replace("\"", ""))
```

Then you can use this display template on your fields.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SupplierName, "RemoveSlashes")
```

This will then pass your item to the DisplayTemplate and output the code in the display template.